# how to use admob native ads without NativeAppInstallAdView or NativeContentAdView

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

we would like to use the native ads feature of admob and display them in our own UI.

the NativeContentAd provides access to different properties, like image, logo, text, but we cannot access the call to action url.

all samples use NativeAppInstallAdView or NativeContentAdView.

is there a way to do that, to have our own UI without NativeAppInstallAdView or NativeContentAdView?

thanks.

Comment: You may want to check [custom native ad formats](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/native#displaying_custom_native_ad_formats). Such formats differ from system-defined ones in that publishers have the power to define their own "templates," or lists of assets, that make up an ad.

Comment: thanks LexJulienne. the link you provided is for "SDK for DFP Users", not for AdMob. what is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own layout xml, and wrap it with an `NativeAppInstallAdView` or `NativeContentAdView`.
The wrapper view adds the ad-choices icon on the top-right corner over your custom design.

See: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native#the_ad_view_classes